# create subscription for mailbox of all users of an organization

Tags: web-services, graph, outlook, office365, subscription

Good Afternoon

I have created a subscription on incoming mails for an individual user but I want to do it at the tenant level. How i do that one.

Thank you in advance.

i.e. one subscription for all users of an tenant. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, it is not possible.